# How can i install warp10-ext-flows without internet connection on my linux VM

Tags: warp10

I'd like to use "warp10-ext-flows" on my warp10 installation but i dont have internet acces on this VM.
Is there a simple solution to install it manually ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To manually install FLoWS:

1. Download the jar. You can find the download link on the right of [the FLoWS' WarpFleet page](https://warpfleet.senx.io/browse/io.warp10/warp10-ext-flows).
2. Put the jar in the classpath of your Warp 10 instance. By default any jar in the `${WARP10_HOME}/lib` directory is added to the classpath.
3. Add the following line to the `${WARP10_HOME}/etc/70--extensions.conf`:

```
warpscript.extension.flows = io.warp10.ext.flows.FLoWSWarpScriptExtension
```

4. Restart your instance and the extension is now loaded and available to use.

This works in the same way for other extensions or plugins.

Note that `${WARP10_HOME}` is usually not defined in your shell, it's just a way to indicate the directory where you deployed Warp 10.

Comment: I was putting the jar in ${WARP10_HOME}/jars. All works now, thanks you for the fast answer.